# SonataAdmin does not show the left side menu, nor the links that the "admin.users" or the "admin.people" should have

Tags: php, symfony, admin, sonata

The problem is that I can use SonataAdmin, I am loaded and I can use the CRUD, but the menu on the left shows only "sonata project". I know I can modify the template by default and add links to custom drivers, but right now I do not need that, what I'm looking for is that the menu be generated with the entities included in the CRUD, as I have seen that it is generated to other people in the network, but I am not able to see it as I have to do it (Yes, I have looked at the documentation a lot -.-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate the menu, you have to set the `group` option of your admins.
[As described in the documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/dashboard.html#configuring-the-admin-list), there are two ways to do that.

Either add it to your admins services:

```
services:
    app.admin.post:
        class: App\Admin\PostAdmin
        tags:
            - name: sonata.admin
              manager_type: orm
              group: "Content"
        [...]
    app.admin.page:
        class: App\Admin\PageAdmin
        tags:
            - name: sonata.admin
              manager_type: orm
              group: "Blog"
```

Or set all the groups in the config file:

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            app.admin.group.content:
                items:
                    - app.admin.post

            app.admin.group.blog:
                items:
                    - sonata.admin.page
```

Comment: This is fine. And, Do you know why they voted me negatively?

Comment: I don't know. Your question could be better written / structured. It's maybe the reason... If my answer helped, please could you mark it as accepted?

Comment: Well, very friendly people around here ... -.-. And yes, your answer helps me, it would be perfect if you add it by adding that the user must have the role `ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN` so that the configuration you expose is visible and the menu appears. (I have already voted *)